# Is there any safe way to mask an url that will be rendered to the user?

Tags: security, authentication, url, owasp

The problem is the following:

I have a number of public urls, for example:

> http://www.example.com/randomHash

The problem is that I want to share it with an specific set of users but I don't want them to be able to share the link with other unauthorized people.

The first solution that I thought was to create an interface that deals with the authentication and masks the original url, showing to the user my auth domain. The problem is that the user can easily find the url and I could not find a reference of how to do that. Is there any solution in this line ? Or another approach is better suited?

Comment: This is not solvable in the general case. In specific cases it may be possible to design mitigations that provide limited protection. It will matter exactly how the user is allowed to interact with the information and the system (the hardware and network for example). You'll need to give details of how the user interacts, and what kinds of attacks you're trying to protect against. This should off-topic here, but with that additional information it could be on-topic for security.stackexchange.com

Comment: Something that may help is to make the links expire in a short time period, or even after a single use. Once the user has clicked the link once, subsequent access can be verified with a cookie, rather than with the link's hash content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the URL is openly accessible (i.e. not behind any form of authentication) this cannot be solved. The reason is fairly straight forward, the URL is sent to the client, as you cannot trust the client there is no way of guaranteeing that the client will keep the URL safe.

Additionally, it is worth baring in mind that URLs are in general not considered secret, this means that products for example proxies and caches will log the URL and the logs are available to admins etc. Finally in larger organisations tools like [urldefense](https://www.proofpoint.com/uk/resources/data-sheets/essentials-url-defense) will strip out URLs from e-mails and replace them with their own URLs to ensure that anyone clicking on the link will go through their system. This means that there will be solutions that redirect to your URL.

The typical solution to this is to authenticate the user and have a solution that will redirect any users that haven't authenticated to the login screen when they try to access the URL directly. The exact implementation for this depends a lot on your current environment, programming language, framework etc.

Comment: This solves the question. As I said in the text, the purpose was to protect general public links, for example the ones generated by publishing gsheets files.